# String from byte does not display if "\n" is inside

Tags: java, android, string

I am trying to read `bytes` received via a bluetooth connection and convert it to `String`

**Monitor input stream**

```
public void run() {
            Log.i(TAG, "BEGIN mConnectedThread");
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
            int bytes;

            // Keep listening to the InputStream while connected
            while (true) {
                try {
                    // Read from the InputStream
                    bytes = mmInStream.read(buffer);

                    // Send the obtained bytes to the UI Activity
                    mHandler.obtainMessage(MainActivity.MESSAGE_READ, bytes, -1, buffer)
                            .sendToTarget();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "disconnected", e);
                    connectionLost();
                    // Start the service over to restart listening mode
                    BluetoothChatService.this.start();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
```

**MainActivity when I receive, the log statement does not seem to get called if there is multiple lines. If it is just a single line, it's fine**

```
 case MESSAGE_READ:
                    byte[] readBuf = (byte[]) msg.obj;
                    String readMessage = new String(readBuf, 0, msg.arg1);
                    Log.d(TAG, "Incoming message: " + readMessage); // does not get called when there's a linebreak.
```

When I try to check if the string contains certain info as such, it doesn't get called even though the String I received does contain it.

**For example**, given if I received`readMessage = "Obstacle String\nStart of 2nd line"`
The following statement doesn't get called

```
 if (readMessage.contains("Obstacle String"))
```

*But when I try to set the `readMessage` to some `TextView`, it is able to display the string correctly.*

Comment: Have you used your debugger to check that the string contains what you think it contains?

Comment: Went to debug, it actually reads `"Obstacle String\r\nStart of 2nd line"` Which actually does contain the required string condition to enter my `if` loop. So why does it not do so?

Comment: 'When I try to check if the string contains certain info' how?

Comment: @EJP As per my question the `if branch` statement. It actually does go inside, sorry for the wrong info, as I was testing whether it enter the `if` branch just by relying on a single log statement that logs to Android's logcat. And that statement fails to execute as per my answer.

Comment: **What** '`if` branch statement'?

Answer (score 0):

For some reason Android logcat does not seems to handle `\r`

So, I trimmed the string as such

```
readMessage = readMessage.replaceAll("\r", "");
```